# Inserting data with pandas or psycopg with a serial key?

Tags: pandas, psycopg2

I have a simple dimension table which is storing all of the unique dimensions from several files.

In postgres, I made the table:

```
CREATE TABLE dimension_purpose (
  purpose_key SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  purpose text NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Now I am trying to add the new rows to this table efficiently. I am able to identify the new dimensions easily (using pandas), but I am having trouble inserting them into this table. I typically use

```
def load_to_database(table_name, file_object, header=True):
    fake_conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine).raw_connection()
    fake_cur = fake_conn.cursor()
    sql = 'COPY {} FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER'.format(table_name)
    fake_cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=file_object)
    fake_conn.commit()
    fake_cur.close()
```

If I try to bulk copy, I get an error that 'purpose' is not an integer (it is trying to insert itself into the purpose_key field).

What is the best way to insert a single column of data into the purpose field and then have the SERIAL purpose_key update automatically?

Can I do this with df.to_sql if my df is just one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the columns in your `COPY` command, e.g.

```
COPY dimension_purpose (purpose) FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html